# Can slurm run 3 seperate computers as one "node"?

Tags: slurm

I'm an intern that's been tasked with installing slurm across three compute units running ubuntu. How things work now is people ssh into one of the compute units and run a job on there, since all three units share memory through nfs mounting. Otherwise they are separate machines though.

My issue is that from what I've read in the documentation, it seems like when installing slurm I would specify each of these compute units as a completely separate node, and any jobs I'd like to run that use multiple cores would still be limited by how many cores are available on the individual node. My supervisor has told me however that the three units should be installed as a single node, and when a job comes in that needs more cores than available on a single compute unit, slurm should just use all the cores. The intention is that we won't be changing how we execute jobs (like a parallelized R script), just "wrapping" them in a sbatch script before sending them to slurm for scheduling and execution.

So is my supervisor correct in that slurm can be used to run our parallelized scripts unchanged with more cores than available on a single machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a script on more cores than available is nonsense. It does not provide any performance increase, rather the oposite, as more threads have to be managed but the computing power is the same.

But he is right in the sense that you can wrap your current script and send it to SLURM for execution using the whole node. But the three machines will be three nodes. They cannot work as a single node because, well, they are not a single node/machine. They do not share either memory nor busses, nor peripherals... they just share some disk thru the network.

You say that

> any jobs I'd like to run that use multiple cores would still be limited by how many cores are available on the individual node

but that's the current situation with SSH. Nothing is lost by using SLURM to manage the resources. In fact, SLURM will take care of giving each job the proper resources and avoiding other users interfering with your computations.

Your best bet: create a cluster of three nodes as usual and let people send their jobs asking for as many resources they need without exceeding the available resources.